# Probability of an event given two dependent events

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

how do you calculate: Pr(X| Y,Z) if Y and Z are dependent events.

for example:

Pr(V1) for being true is 0.7

Pr(V2) for being true is 0.4

V1 and V2 are both pointing to V3. V1 and V2 do not point to anything else.

for the truth table:

V3: true

V2: true

V1: true

pr(V3|V1,V2) = 0.6

How did the truth table come up with 0.6?

another truth table:
V3: true

V1: true

V2: false

Pr(V3|V1,V2) = 0.4

How did they come up with 0.4?

Comment: They probably invented them for the purpose of asking the question.